# Why do promoters in public companies sell their shares and reduce their holdings?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets

Promoters in public companies can sell their shares and reduce their holdings. Why do they want to reduce their holdings?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question actually means.  Do you mean why do people promote a company, but then sell their shares in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "promoter"

Comment: In your other question you ask about promoter. It would be best, if you defined that term in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Promoters in public companies can sell their shares and reduce their holdings. Why do they want to reduce their holdings?

There are a million companies that I can own shares in. Which one I want to own shares in depends on my risk preference, my investment time horizon, the exposure to external events that various industries have, and so on. It would be a shocking coincidence if the company that it made the most sense for me to invest in also happened to be the one that I was promoting.

Also, that tends to put too many eggs in one basket. You may already haver your career advancement, your professional reputation, and your salary tied up in the company. Imagine if you had all those things tied up with a company that does cruises and then the global pandemic hits. You would, at least, want to have your investments in some other economic sector, wouldn't you?